# PyMySQL Insert NULL or a String

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I tried to insert a field (`title`) with PyMySQL that can be `NULL` or a string. But it doesn't work.

```
query = """
    INSERT INTO `chapter` (title, chapter, volume)
    VALUES ("%s", "%s", %d)
"""

cur.execute(query % (None, "001", 1))
cur.execute(query % ("Title", "001", 1))
```

This code inserts `None` into the database. If I remove the double quote around the first `%s`, it throws an error:

```
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'None' in 'field list'")
```

What can I do to insert NULL?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1) Never use string formatting for SQL.

2) Try the following:

```
query = """
INSERT INTO `chapter` (title, chapter, volume)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
"""
cur.execute(query, (None, "001", 1))
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Never use string formatting for sql"? I am a mysql beginner, doing something similar to the OP.

Comment: @ScheissSchiesser, it may lead to sql injection. So it is better to use parameter binding like in the code sample above

Comment: what if you want `None` in a number column, like `volume` above?

Comment: Oh...I've been using string formatting for SQL for a long while...I thought it would be fine as long as I used the `bleach` module to `bleach.clean` any input. Is that wrong?