# How to use MySQL's NULL and DEFAULT keywords for INSERT query in python?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm trying to run an INSERT query via a python program for thousands of records which have nullable fields as well. My requirement is such that the result set is transformed into key-value pairs in a dictionary and then parse the values into a list for executing INSERT query. However, when I try to add a NULL value to an int type field and execute INSERT via the program, I hit an error as shown below:

> Warning: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column
>   'category_id' at row 1")   result = self._query(query)

In the MySQL DB if I execute the query with 'NULL' or 'DEFAULT' keyword for the value of 'category_id', the value gets updated as NULL as expected.

Can someone please help zero in on what I'm missing here? Following is my code snippet:

```
    for s in result:
        temp_dict = {}
        for key, value in enumerate(s):
            if value is None:
                temp_dict[key] = pymysql.NULL
            else:
                temp_dict[key] = str(value)
```

Comment: share your table structure , one question category_id allow null?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Yes category_id is nullable.

Comment: could you please share your insert statement

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin The query formed by python looks something like 'INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('a', 'b', .... 'NULL'). In this case the NULL field in the end happens to be of int type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyMySQL Insert NULL or a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698722/pymysql-insert-null-or-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

i think null is being converted to string as a result you got error
could you try by passing the value None, not "NULL":

```
value = None
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (`column1`) VALUES (%s)", (value,))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a field expecting an Integer, MySQl replace a NULL field with 0 which should be the default value.

As you query you could use the `IS NULL` to single out the values with null values which you could then manipulate the value to an integer e.g 0

or you could tweek the query to only return values without a null at category_id by adding

`WHERE category_id IS NOT NULL`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE category_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I'm trying to do a bulk insert here. I would want the code to be able to handle this for any NULL value irrespective of field type.